# Why does target="_blank" not work in Chrome on a Samsung device?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, samsung-mobile

I'm setting up an `<a>` tag to open a new tab with a telephone number.

Originally I had an `a` tag with the phone number and target `blank`, and this was supported on chrome on Google Pixel, iOS 12 and iOS 11, as well as Safari on iOS 11 and iOS 12.

However, on Chrome using a Samsung device, target `blank` only opened a new tab with `tel:1111111111` (but with our actual number) in the address bar.

We've now switched to target `_self`, which works fine for our use case, but I'm interested in why target `_blank` doesn't work in Chrome on a Samsung device.

Comment: @hybridskittle, The most probably your samsung device have popup blocker on the chrome and its didn't let to open new popup.

Comment: @jeprubio http for our development servers.

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh the new tab did open, however, with the `tel:11111111` (but with the actual phone number) in the address bar. is this simply expected behavior?